# Sorting objects by the return value of a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I recently encountered some problems while trying to sort a set of objects.

The objects I'd like to sort are subclasses of NSManagedObject.
I want to sort the objects by a 'global_index', which is, however, not a property in my model. It's just a getter `-(NSInteger)globalIndex {...}` each of the objects implements. Inside this method, I do some complex calculation which cannot be done with a simple sort descriptor.

Now, my question: Is there a way to make an NSSortDescriptor **sort the objects** by the **return value** of a method?

I really want to use a sort descriptor because it's (IMO) the only way to make use of NSFetchedResultsController's cool features. Or is there a way to tell the controller how to sort the fetched objects? Like...
`- (NSArray *)sortObjects:(NSSet *)objects {...}`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW11),

> The SQL store, on the other hand, compiles the predicate and sort descriptors to SQL and evaluates the result in the database itself. This is done primarily for performance, but it means that evaluation happens in a non-Cocoa environment, and so sort descriptors (or predicates) that rely on Cocoa cannot work. The supported sort selectors are compare: and caseInsensitiveCompare:, localizedCompare:, localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:, and localizedStandardCompare: (the latter is Finder-like sorting, and what most people should use most of the time). In addition you cannot sort on transient properties using the SQLite store.

The easy workaround is to save the order with each object (which is a pain when you need to insert an object between two others, but that's a problem with trying to implement an efficient ordered collection in a database).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply passing `@"globalIndex"` as the sort descriptor's key? That should work fine since there's an accessor for that key.

Comment: I've written a few variations on this approach – I can confirm this ought to work based on what OP described.

Comment: This works fine when sorting the objects **after** the fetch has been performed.  
However, it doesn't work when using it as a SortDescriptor for the FetchRequest. When used in a FetchRequest the app crashes with `'keypath globalIndex not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Tag id=2>'`

Comment: @Jenox, sorry, I missed that you wanted to use this sort descriptor in a fetch request. You can't use a key like your `globalIndex` in a fetch request for the same reason that [you can't use a transient property in a fetch request](http://tinyurl.com/3fdrjxk): the objects *don't exist* until the fetch request has executed. You can't send a message to a record in an SQLite data store. ;-) Instead, you'll need to fetch the objects first and then sort them, and that may mean that you can't use NSFetchedResultsController here.

Comment: @Jenox, It'd be nice if NSFetchedResultsController let you specify a sort descriptor to be applied to the fetched results. You might consider [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com/) to ask for that feature.

Comment: @Caleb, presumably you could do it by subclassing NSFetchedResultsController and overriding the appropriate methods. You'd probably want to specify `additionalSortOrder` and `additionalPredicate`, with perhaps an optimization for the case where the database can return "almost-sorted" results. What you lose is the main efficiency gain of NSFetchedResultsController: not needing to load 10000 objects from the DB before displaying them.

Comment: @tc, could you please give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Jenox, subclass NSFetchedResultsController, overriding `-fetchedObjects` and `-sections` to return re-sorted objects/sections. I'm pretty sure this will work, but may be slow (and will be much slower than NSFRC when you have a lot of objects).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to 'trick' NSSortDescriptor into using your global index method like it would any regular accessor method (the accessor should conform to the expectations of [Key-Value Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-BAJEAIEE)). In other words, treat *globalIndex* as a property of your NSManagedObject subclasses and have the following methods in each one of them.

```
-(NSInteger) globalIndex {
    ...
}


-(void) setGlobalIndex: (NSInteger) idx {
    ...
}
```

To make things even easier, you can define a subclass of NSManagedObject with your extra methods and extend your subclasses from that (or create a [Category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html), either way). Should work just fine.

Comment: `-setGlobalIndex:` is only necessary if the property is mutable, and a sort descriptor has no business mutating the objects it's sorting. Supplying `-globalIndex` as the OP is already doing should be all that's needed.

Comment: I'm not suggesting the sort descriptor 'mutate' his objects. I am suggesting he make his globalIndex property compliant with standard property accessors if it isn't already, so that the sorted descriptor is able to access it.

Comment: I agree -- I'm just saying that since there's no need for mutability, @Jenox's classes are already sufficiently KVC compliant for the key `globalIndex` without a setter. There are a lot of *ifs* involved in KVC compliance: you need a setter *if* the property is mutable, you need various methods *if* the property is to-many, and others *if* you want KVV. If Jenox wants to modify the `globalIndex` property using KVC, then a setter would be required, but there's no need for just sorting.